# Python - append a list with uncertain length to specific columns in order

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a program returns a list with uncertain length of numbers each time, and I want to append the list to dataframe. Each time, I know the column order to append but I don't know the length of the list.

```
df = DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

If the column order is B, C, D, E, F and the list return 3 numbers (2, 4, 6), then it will be

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 4 | 6 |  |  |

If the column order is E, D, C, B, A and the list return 2 numbers (4, 6), then it will be

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 4 | 6 |  |  |
|  |  |  | 6 | 4 |  |

Again I know the column order but I don't know how many numbers will be returned.

Comment: I have modify as df.loc[0, c] = data_list[i], and it works now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

datum = [2, 3, 4]
order = ["A", "C", "D"]

data.loc[len(data.index), order] = datum
print(data)
```

This gives:

```
   A    B  C  D    E    F
0  2  NaN  3  4  NaN  NaN
```

[`data.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) stores the axis labels for `data`.

Here, it is `Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')`. Getting the length of this object allows us to add a new row to the data frame when used with `data.loc`.

For example, if we try:

```
order = ["A", "C", "F", "D"]
datum = [-1, 0, 100, 5]

data.loc[len(data.index), order] = datum
print(data, "\n")
print("Index of data:", data.index)
```

it gives:

```
    A    B  C  D    E    F
0   2  NaN  3  4  NaN  NaN
1  -1  NaN  0  5  NaN  100

Index of data: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

say col order list is `col_names` and list with unknown variables is `num_list` then you can try;

```
for i,c in enumerate(col_names):
   if i > len(num_list):
      break
   df.iloc[x][c] = num_list[I]
```

**Update**
or

```
for i,num in enumerate(num_list):
   df.iloc[x][col_names[i]] = num
```

Not elegant. But will do the job. `x` is the location of dataframe for the datapoint.

Comment: i got IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Updated the answer with a break both codes d the same thing.